# What qualitative studies are there into mindfulness?

Tags: emotion, therapy

What [qualitative studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qualitative_psychological_research), e.g. open ended interviews, are there into mindfulness therapy?

I've been skeptical about its use, wondered if it was kinda faddy. But it occurs to me that a lot of despair type emotions may have their root in being unable to relax and enjoy life. Surely meditation is linked with that?

Comment: I've voted to close this as "too broad" even thought @Chris gave an awesome answer, because it basically involved him citing an entire Wikipedia article. As a general rule of thumb, if someone has to go to Wikipedia and copy giant sections to answer a question, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia often provides references to scientific studies and the [Wikipedia article on Mindfulness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness) is no exception.

The **main section** of the article has

> ...Studies have also shown that rumination and worry contribute to mental illnesses such as depression and anxiety,<sup>[13][14]</sup> and that mindfulness-based interventions are effective in the reduction of both rumination and worry.<sup>[13][15]</sup>
>
> Mindfulness practice is being employed in psychology to alleviate a variety of mental and physical conditions, such as bringing about reductions in depression symptoms,<sup>[16][17][18]</sup> reducing stress,<sup>[17][19][20]</sup> anxiety,<sup>[16][17][20]</sup> and in the treatment of drug addiction.<sup>[21][22][23]</sup> Recent studies demonstrate that mindfulness meditation significantly attenuates pain through multiple, unique mechanisms.<sup>[24]</sup> It has gained worldwide popularity as a distinctive method to handle emotions.
>
> Clinical studies have documented both physical and mental health benefits of mindfulness in different patient categories as well as in healthy adults and children.<sup>[3][25][26]</sup>

plus

> Research on the neural perspective of how mindfulness meditation works suggests that it exerts its effects in components of attention regulation, body awareness and emotional regulation.<sup>[34]</sup> When considering aspects such as sense of responsibility, authenticity, compassion, self-acceptance and character, studies have shown that mindfulness meditation contributes to a more coherent and healthy sense of self and identity.<sup>[35][36]</sup> Neuroimaging techniques suggest that mindfulness practices such as mindfulness meditation are associated with “changes in the anterior cingulate cortex, insula, temporo-parietal junction, fronto-limbic network and default mode network structures."<sup>[37][38]</sup> Further, mindfulness-induced emotional and behavioral changes have been found to be related to functional and structural changes in the brain.<sup>[38]</sup>

There is also a **scientific research** section

> Mindfulness has gained increasing empirical attention ever since 1970.<sup>[120][unreliable source?]</sup> According to a 2015 systematic review and meta-analysis of systematic reviews of RCTs, evidence supports the use of mindfulness programs to alleviate symptoms of a variety of mental and physical disorders.<sup>[25]</sup> Other reviews report similar findings.<sup>[19][22][33]</sup> Further, mindfulness meditation appears to bring about favorable structural changes in the brain,<sup>[32][37][121]</sup> and may also prevent or delay the onset of mild cognitive impairment and Alzheimer's disease.<sup>[122]</sup> Mindfulness proved to be effective also in enhancing people’s capacity to self-regulate.<sup>[123]</sup>

### References

These are provided in the [full article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mindfulness)

This question is close to being put on hold or closed and to indicate why, it would produce a posting which is much longer than the standard laid out in the [help center](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions),

> if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format

plus, there are so many referenced studies and articles of scientific research connected to this (I counted 25 in total - 156 in the full article) that providing a full list of references here would take me an age to provide in full (with weblinks etc.) on this site.

Comment: well i was specifically asking for qualitative studies -- which makes sense right?